# concatenation with " in Azure Data Factory set variable

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to concatenate three strings which include ", but Azure data factory is adding it as ". How do we get rid of the \ character? I have one set of variables with a returning value of ABCDEFG and I wanted to concatenate it with other data to populate it like the variable: {"value"}:{"ABCDEFG"}

I am using the syntax in set variable like:

```
@replace(concat('{','"','value:',variables('requiredvalue'),'}'),'\ ','')
```

and I am getting the output value as `"value": "{"value:ABCDEFG}"`.

The output I am expecting is `{"value"}:{"ABCDEFG"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below expression to achieve your requirement.

```
@concat('{','"','value"}:{"',variables('req_value'),'"}')
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

> Question is how do we get rid of \ character

Here, you cannot replace or remove `\` from the above string because when you display any string result `\` acts as an escape character for the `"`. So, whenever you have `"` in a string, it will add `\` before it by default.

But, it won't affect the any string operations on it, its just an escape character when you are displaying the value. You can go ahead with this string as per your requirement further.

For sample demo, here I am checking the lengths of the above variable(with `\`) and normal string `{"value"}:{"ABCDEFG"}`.

I have created an integer variable `length` and took two set variable activities on same variable.

First, I have given the value as `@length(variables('json_string'))` to check the above variable length where it has `\`.

Then, I am checking normal string length `@length('{"value"}:{"ABCDEFG"}')` which doesn't have any `\`.

[image]

**Upon debugging length of above variable with `\`:**

[image]

**Length of normal string without `\`:**

[image]

You can see that both have same length. So, you don't need to remove or replace the `\` as it won't affect the data operations on the string. You can use the same variable as per your requirement.

Comment: Appreciate for sharing the details, so to confirm I can pass this variable to any subsequent activities and "\" will not impact. Actually we are planning supply this value to vault secret.